# What is the difference between kdeplot's "cut" and "clip" parameters?

Tags: seaborn

In Seaborn's `kdeplot`, is there a semantic difference between the `cut` and the `clip` parameters? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Seaborn's doc](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html):

```
cut:  number, optional
    Factor, multiplied by the smoothing bandwidth, that determines how far the evaluation grid extends past the extreme datapoints. When set to 0, truncate the curve at the data limits.
```

```
clip: pair of numbers or None, or a pair of such pairs

    Do not evaluate the density outside of these limits.
```

Comment: I can read the documentation on my own. But I don't understand the differences. If I could downvote this answer, I would.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you don't understand. Could you please elaborate which part of the doc is confusing you?